# How to set jnlp port in jenkins through command line?

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I am running an ansible playbook which install jenkins and need to run cli.jar to run multiple scripts. It needs jnlp port whcih I want to set it up through ansible shell command. But it seems to be failing.

```
 - name: Set jnlp port
   shell: 'curl -X POST -d ".useSecurity=on&slaveAgentPort.type=fixed&value=49187&core%3Aapply=true&json=%7B%22useSecurity%22%3A+%7B%22slaveAgentPort%22%3A+%7B%22type%22%3A+%22fixed%22%2C+%22value%22%3A+%2249187%22%7D%7D%2C+%22core%3Aapply%22%3A+%22true%22%7D" --header "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://localhost:8080//configureSecurity/configure'
   remote_user: jenkins
   become: yes
   become_method: sudo
```

Running with -vvv options gives:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/vagrant/ansible/roles/jenkins1.648/tasks/plugins.yml': line 37, column 370, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- name: Check update center and push it to the update URL
  shell: 'curl -X POST -d .useSecurity=on&slaveAgentPort.type=fixed&value=49187&core%3Aapply=true&json=%7B%22useSecurity%22%3A+%7B%22slaveAgentPort%22%3A+%7B%22type%22%3A+%22fixed%22%2C+%22value%22%3A+%2249187%22%7D%7D%2C+%22core%3Aapply%22%3A+%22true%22%7D" --header "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://localhost:8080//configureSecurity/configure' -vvv
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ^ here
This one looks easy to fix.  It seems that there is a value started
with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
with the same kind of quote.  For instance:

    when: "ok" in result.stdout

Could be written as:

   when: '"ok" in result.stdout'

Or equivalently:

   when: "'ok' in result.stdout"
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
unbalanced quotes.  If starting a value with a quote, make sure the
line ends with the same set of quotes.  For instance this arbitrary
example:

    foo: "bad" "wolf"

Could be written as:

    foo: '"bad" "wolf"'

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

Comment: @techraf : yes it does when I just try to run it from command line

Comment: @techraf I am adding -vvv after curl command ends. Can you please elaborate how you are expecting it to be

Comment: Okay I just want to set TCP/jnlp port in jenkins and the same curl command works fine directly but not with ansible. I am trying to find a solution why it is failing.

Comment: your `-vvv` is outside the signle quote; it should be inside it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are okay with invoking the jenkins-cli groovy command via ansible, this works for me:

```
def instance=jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance
instance.setSlaveAgentPort(9999)
instance.save()
```

Ansible task could look like:

```
- name: Set jnlp port
  shell: 'java -jar /tmp/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 groovy /tmp/fix-jnlp-port.groovy'
  remote_user: jenkins
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
```

Obviously, you will need to download the jenkins-cli.jar file ... and have java installed beforehand.

This presumes that the JNLP port will be sent out (via some header) by Jenkins and will be accessible locally.

Alternatively, you may be able to pass that groovy code to the script console using curl (I have not tried that). This link shares examples:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console

```
curl --data-urlencode "script=$(<./somescript.groovy)" http://jenkins/scriptText
```

And just to remove the dependency on curl, feel free to try with get_url and uri ansible modules.

Comment: This looks interesting. Will try that. Thanks!

Comment: Will that go ahead and setup a port permanently or it will just use that port temporarily for script

Comment: instance.save() will make it persist across jenkins process restarts. If you omit that, the jnlp port would be set only until jenkins process shuts down. In other words, it is not per groovy script execution.